# How to format a date to be displayed in 2 lines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting

I have a label called dateLabel that displays when did a user last time got logged in:

```
dateLabel.Text = "Sist gang logget inn: " + string.Format("{0:d}\n{0:T}", Session["LastLoginDate"].ToString());
```

What i want i to display the information in 2 different lines. In the first the date and in the one below the time.

- How should i modify my code to achieve this?
- Does it mind if i use a label, or maybe i should use another component?
- Currently in that output there is a duplicate, but i don't understand why, how can i avoid that?

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Can someone give me some tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\n` with `<br/>`
Also replace

```
Session["LastLoginDate"].ToString()
```

with

```
(DateTime)Session["LastLoginDate"]
```

Comment: All given answers were valid. My main mistake, was, i did not use `<br/>` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
dateLabel.Text = string.Format("Sist gang logget inn:{1}{0:d}{1}{0:T}",
                               Session["LastLoginDate"], 
                               "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

@sfrj as far as i know its not possible to wrap the text on asp:label control you can try a text box control instead read on the following link

http://geekswithblogs.net/StealThisCode/archive/2006/03/21/WrapLabels.aspx